# Como remover espaços de uma string no Python sem remover também as quebras de linha?

Tags: python, string

Preciso remover os espaços desnecessários das strings, mas não a quebra entre as linhas. Tenho usado o comando abaixo, que retira os espaços, mas também retira a quebra com o `/n`. Alguém sabe como solucionar?

```
" ".join("   minha  \n string do python    ".split())
```

Resultado do console:

```
'minha string do python'
```

Resultado que eu estou tentando fazer:

```
'minha \n string do python'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quer substituir dois ou mais espaços por apenas um, uma alternativa é usar expressões regulares (regex), através do [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

s = "   minha  \n string do python    "
sem_espacos_a_mais = re.sub(' {2,}', ' ', s).strip(' ')
print(repr(sem_espacos_a_mais)) # 'minha \n string do python'
```

No caso, a regex tem um espaço (repare no espaço logo após o `'` e antes do `{`). Depois o [quantificador](http://regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{2,}` indica "duas ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, estamos procurando por 2 ou mais espaços seguidos, que são substituídos por apenas um espaço.

Mas isso não elimina o espaço do começo e fim da string, então eu uso [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para removê-los.

---

Com [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), você pode passar como parâmetro o espaço, assim ela não elimina as quebras de linha. O problema é que assim você terá várias strings vazias também:

```
print(", ".join(map(repr, s.split(' '))))
# '', '', '', 'minha', '', '\n', 'string', 'do', 'python', '', '', '', ''
```

Mas aí basta usar [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) para eliminar as strings vazias:

```
sem_espacos_a_mais = " ".join(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, s.split(' ')))
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
sem_espacos_a_mais = " ".join(filter(lambda x: x, s.split(' ')))
```

A opção acima funciona porque [strings vazias são consideradas *false*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), e `filter` só pega os elementos para os quais o *lambda* retorna `True` (ou seja, no caso serão as strings não vazias). Você ainda pode passar `None` no lugar do *lambda*, como indicou a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444730/112052), pois neste caso `filter` assume a "função identidade" (que basicamente é o *lambda* acima, que retorna o próprio elemento).

O resultado é o mesmo da solução anterior.

---

Também é possível fazer tudo em uma única regex, mas acho que ela fica complicada demais para valer a pena:

```
sem_espacos_a_mais = re.sub('^ *([^ ])|(?<!^)( ) +|([^ ]) *$', r'\1\2\3', s)
```

Ela usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou"), com 3 opções diferentes:

- `^ *([^ ])`: o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que indica o início da string, seguido de zero ou mais espaços ( `*`), seguido de um caractere que não é espaço (`[^ ]`), **ou**
- `(?<!^)( ) +`: um espaço (`( )`) seguido de um ou mais espaços ( `+`), desde que não seja no início da string (`(?<!^)` é um [*lookbehind* negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) que verifica se o que existe antes não é `^`), **ou**
- `([^ ]) *$`: um caractere que não é espaço, seguido de zero ou mais espaços, e o final da string (`$`)

Repare que alguns trechos estão entre parênteses, pois isso forma [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que eu posso referenciar depois. No caso, a string de substituição (o segundo parâmetro passado para [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)) indica que vou usar `\1\2\3` - `\1` é o primeiro grupo (o primeiro par de parênteses), que no caso é o caractere que não é espaço, logo depois dos espaços do início da string. `\2` é o segundo grupo, que é o espaço que não está no início da string, e `\3` é o terceiro grupo, que é o caractere que não é espaço, antes dos espaços no final da string.

Assim eu preservo esses caracteres e elimino os espaços restantes (se um desses grupos não for capturado, ele é vazio, assim não interfere nas demais substituições). O resultado é o mesmo do código anterior, mas como eu já disse, é um pouco mais complicado e talvez valha mais a pena usar as duas primeiras opções (regex mais simples + `strip` ou `split` + `filter`).

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é gerar uma lista a partir da quebrar da sentença nos espaços(`\x20`) usando [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), da lista gerada filtrar com a função bulti-in [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) as strings vazia e juntar o resultado com [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
s = "   minha  \nstring do python    "

f = lambda s:" ".join(filter(None, [x for x in s.split("\x20")]))

print(f(s))
```

Teste no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/OpenEcstaticWatch

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução alternativa seria:

1. Quebrar a string em linhas;
2. Remover os espaços em branco de cada uma das linhas individualmente;
3. Reunir as linhas em uma string unica novamente.

Veja só:

```
entrada = '  testando \n  minha   \n   string     do      python    '

# Quebra a string em uma lista de linhas
linhas = entrada.split('\n')

# Remove os espacos de cada uma das linhas da lista
linhas = [' '.join(i.split()) for i in linhas]

# Remonta a string a partir da lista de linhas
saida = '\n'.join(linhas)

print(saida)
```

Ou até mesmo:

```
entrada = ' testando \n  minha   \n   string     do      python    '
saida = '\n'.join([' '.join(i.split()) for i in entrada.split('\n')])
print(saida)
```

Saída:

```
testando\nminha\nstring do python
```